# Android SQLite is empty after inserting ContentValues

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing a program. At some place I want to insert some values inside my local database. But if check the db after inserting it is empty. Here is the code

```
LeaderBase sqh = new LeaderBase(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = null;
    if (checkDataBase()){

        sqdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.test7/databases/leader_database.db", null, 0);
    }
    else{

    }

    sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(LeaderBase.USERNAME, String.valueOf(nameRes));
    cv.put(LeaderBase.USERMONEY, moneyRes);
    cv.put(LeaderBase.USERTIME, timeRes);
    cv.put(LeaderBase.UGAMETYPE, gtype);

    sqdb.insert(LeaderBase.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    Cursor cursor2 = sqdb.query(LeaderBase.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
            LeaderBase._ID, LeaderBase.USERNAME }, 
            null, // The columns for the WHERE clause
            null, // The values for the WHERE clause
            null, // don't group the rows
            null, // don't filter by row groups
            null // The sort order
            );
    int check_count = cursor2.getCount();
    sqdb.close();
    sqh.close();
```

The code of LeaderBase class:

```
public class LeaderBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "leader_database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "leader_board";
public static final String UID = "_id";
public static final String USERNAME = "username";
public static final String USERMONEY = "usermoney";
public static final String USERTIME = "usertime";
public static final String UGAMETYPE = "ugametype";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + USERNAME + " VARCHAR(255)," 
        + USERMONEY + " BIGINT," 
        + USERTIME + "INT," 
        + UGAMETYPE + "INT"+
                ");";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
        + TABLE_NAME;


public LeaderBase(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);
}

}
```

The problem is that if I check the value check_count it is zero. And the database is empty.
What's the problem?

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are getting exception because You forgot to add a single space in following of your columns,

```
+ USERTIME + "INT,"+ UGAMETYPE + "INT"+
```

I suggest you to updated your that line with following line,

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + USERNAME + " VARCHAR(255)," 
    + USERMONEY + " BIGINT," 
    + USERTIME + " INT,"         
    + UGAMETYPE + " INT"+");";
```

Note : After doing this change, you simply remove your old application from the device/emulator and then try again. The actual reason behind this is that your create table query is going to execute in `onCreate()` method. So to call this you must uninstall previous application.

Comment: Yes,there was a mistake,thank you. But the problem still remains.

Comment: @146percentRussian, try deleting your existing application and then execute the same code again.

Comment: @146percentRussian, that's because old application has already created table so it was not executing onCreate() method again even if your code is changed.